# Using Patterns in findWithinHorizon method

Tags: java, file-io, methods, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

How do i tell the method to search for a pattern of 65 float (or double) values, all in one line of a text file, that's being read using a file reader then a buffered reader then a scanner.

So that the method:

```
findWithinHorizon(Pattern pattern, int Horizon);
```

Returns all of the 65 float values in that line?

(findWithinHorizon is a method of the Java.util.Scanner class, if that helps)

Comment: Do you need help finding what `pattern` should be? Or what `Horizon` should be? Horizon just needs to be the length of the line. How much regex do you know?

Comment: Well I'm new to the entire idea of regex (Ive never heard the phrase before) and its the  pattern  I'm interested in. As my horizon will be set to 0 to find the next instance of the pattern in the text. I'm specifically interested in how to create a pattern that looks for groups of doubles. So it will search through the text and return the first instance of a line of text containing 65 doubles.

Comment: `regex` is `Regular Expression` which is what `Pattern Matching` is in Java. Also, do you want to match a line that contains exactly 65 doubles? Can it contain more doubles? Can it contain other stuff, but you want to match it as long as it has the 65 doubles? You really need to be specific with pattern matching

Comment: You also need to define double. Do you mean an ACTUAL double precision floating point number, which has a representation? Because that would be really hard. Or do you want any arbitrarily long decimal?

Comment: No it will always contain exactly 65 doubles and each double will be different, so i suppose the doubles are arbitrary, as they are just doubles. As in they will not be actual doubles until they have been scanned and i have parsed the returned string and turned them into doubles, if you see what i mean?

Comment: What I'm saying is that not every decimal is representable by a double. I guess you just want to match any decimal, and on conversion to a double it will cut some precision(potentially)

Comment: So i just want the method to search for a pattern of 65 numbers all in one line with or without decimal places. then return these numbers to me in a string once found so i can parse it and turn the numbers into doubles in an Array.

Comment: yeah i see what you mean but Im not worried about that for now i just want to know how to use the pattern part of the method. Precision can come afterwards once Ive got that working.

Comment: I'm not amazing at regex, maybe someone else will help you. But this is the pattern string that I would try: `(\d+([.]\d+)?){65}` to match a line. I also don't think findWithinHorizon is the right thing to do. Just read 1 line at a time and check if it matches

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `findWithinHorizon()` method, nor do you need to use a regex. You can do it with simple methods from the `Scanner` class and a little bit of looping. First, create a new Scanner whose source is the line to read:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner("myFile.txt");
for(int i = 1; i < lineNumberToRead; ++i)
    file.nextLine();
Scanner line = new Scanner(file.nextLine());
```

Then, create the array and get the values from `line`:

```
double[] array = new double[65];
for(int j = 0; j < array.length && line.hasNextDouble(); ++j)
    array[j] = line.nextDouble();
```

**EDIT:** Since you said that there was a token in which the 65 decimals start on, replace the first code sample in this answer with the following code sample:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner("myFile.txt");
file.useDelimiter(tokenBeforeDecimals);
file.next();
Scanner line = new Scanner(file.nextLine());
```